# How do I get Id in the URL to display comments with Symfony 5?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, controller, doctrine

I'm coding a blog with Symfony 5 and I have issues getting the Id from the URL to display comments from my Database.

To sum up :
 - I have a view "/fiche/{id}" wish displays specific game informations. 
 - People can leave a comment below, the comment goes in Database with a foreign Key named "jeu_id" wish is the game where the comment were posted.

- The goal is to display now all the comments wish were posted on this specific game. I want to display all the comments with foreign key "jeu_id" wish is in the url "/fiche/{id}".

Here's the method in my controller :

```
     /**
     * @Route("/fiche/{id}", name="fiche", methods={"POST", "GET"})
     */
    public function fiche($id, Jeux $jeux, Request $request): Response
    {
        $id = (int)$request->get('id');
        $commentaires = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Jeux::class)->find($id);

        $commentaire = new Commentaires();
        $commentaire->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime("NOW"));
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $commentaire->setJeu($jeux);
        $form = $this->createForm(CommentairesType::class, $commentaire);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        //test variable
        //dd($id);
        dd($commentaire->getJeu($id));

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($commentaire);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('liste');
        }
        return $this->render('main/fiche.html.twig', [
            'commentaires' => $commentaires,
            'jeux' => $jeux,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

Here's the concern variables in entity "Commentaires" :

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Jeux::class, inversedBy="commentaires")
     * @JoinColumn(name="jeu_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $jeu;

    public function getJeu(): ?Jeux
    {
        return $this->jeu;
    }

    public function setJeu($jeu): self
    {
        $this->jeu = $jeu;

        return $this;
    }
```

Here's the concern variables in entity "Jeux" :

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Commentaires::class, mappedBy="jeu", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $commentaires;

    /**
     * @return Collection|Commentaires[]
     */
    public function getCommentaires(): Collection
    {
        return $this->commentaires;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry its not very clear for me, at which point you're having troubles? Can you explain whats exactly not working?

Comment: The variable "commentaires" returns nothing, It's supposed to display all the comments with a specific foreign key ( the id in the url )

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? To get the ID is pretty simple, as your controller already contains `$id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the right way would be something like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/fiche/{jeux}", 
 * name="fiche"
 */
public function fiche(Request $request, Jeux $jeux, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(CommentaireType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $commentaire = $form->getData();
        $commentaire->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime("NOW"));
        $jeux->addCommentaire($commentaire);

        $em->persist($commentaire);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('liste');
    }

    return $this->render('main/fiche.html.twig', [
        'commentaires' => $jeux->getCommentaires(),
        'jeux' => $jeux,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a clean version of mine sir, many thanks !
But when I display {{ commentaires }} in my view "fiche.html.twig" there's an error :

Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string

Comment: `{{ commentaires }}` is the Collection of your Commentair Entities, so you would need to do something like `{% for commentaire in commentaires%} {{ commentaire.TEXT_ACCESSOR }} {% endfor %}`

Comment: Many many thanks Samuel, it works perfectly and you were very helpful ;)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - what have you changed and why?

Comment: For more explanation of the answer, I just added 'commentaires' => $jeux->getCommentaires(), to the return. And of course the code is cleaner and more understandable written like he did.